# Using `ERDAS IMG` in `Raster Calculator` Fails

Tags: qgis, erdas-imagine

I recently used a `ERDAS IMG` raster layer in a calculation with the `Raster Calculator`. Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzqPT.png) shows the original image and Figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvGSt.png) shows how I am using the `Raster Calculator` to "duplicate" the layer. Figure [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaaFc.png) shows the result, where the on the fly layer failed to correctly generate. please help me understand what is causing this issue. Thanks.
[image: Original ERDAS IMG]
[image: Raster calculation.]
[image: The result.]

Comment: OK after doing something else and them coming back to this I was able to fix it. It seems to be a bug with QGIS since when I write the file to the disk instead of creating a temporary file it works fine.